# Error building android XML layout, r file not generating

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

So my only layout in my program right now is this activity_main file. I have a MainActivity class. Im getting a build error when saving the xml file and also my R file is not being generated. I read the R file not generating has to do with an xml error. The errors aren't being caught by eclipse in my cml even when it is building. I've included my string xml file, layout file, and android manifest. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

---

### Strings XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">django mouse</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="welcome_header">Welcome to Django</string>
    <string name="start_instructions">To begin enter your local ip address and then click the start button</string>
    <string name="pebb_accel_header">Pebble Accelerometer Data</string>
    <string name="main_x_coordinate">X: </string>
    <string name="main_y_coordinate">Y: </string>
    <string name="main_z_coordinate">Z: </string>
    <string name="up_button">up</string>
    <string name="down_button">down</string>
    <string name="left_button">left</string>
    <string name="right_button">right</string>
    <string name="click_button">click</string>
    <string name="start_button">start</string>

</resources>
```

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/welcome_header"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/start_stop_instructions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="75dp"
            android:text="@string/start_instructions"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome_sub_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/start_stop_instructions"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/pebb_accel_header"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/accel_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/pebb_accel_header"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_x_coordinate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/main_x_coordinate"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_y_coordinate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/main_y_coordinate"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_z_coordinate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/main_z_coordinate"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/up_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/accel_data"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/up_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/down_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/up_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:text="@string/down_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/left_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/up_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/up_button"
            android:text="@string/left_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/up_button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/up_button"
            android:text="@string/right_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/click_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/up_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_button"
            android:text="@string/click_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/start_button"

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.housedroid.djangomouse"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.housedroid.djangomouse.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your last button is missing a closing /> Correct the error, do a clean, and rebuild project. I'm surprised Eclipse didn't show the error, there should have been a squiggly red underline under activity_main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the last `Button` tag in your `activity_main.xml`
2. Have you define something like `colors.xml`?

Comment: Thanks! That was one of the problems, I found a few other issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan mentioned add /> to last Button tag and do a clean and rebuild project